# GROOVY: Split the string into substrings and pair them with the key

Tags: string, groovy, split

I need to split the string into substrings and pair them with the key value.
I'm new to the groovy language, so I'd appreciate it if you can help :)

I have this:

```
{"key": "a", "tag": ""},
{"key": "b", "tag": "one, two"}
```

I want to get this

```
{"key": "a", "tag": ""},
{"key": "b", "tag": "one"}
{"key": "b", "tag": "two"}
```

Comment: Did you tried smth? Could you please share with your drafts?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it. I'd suggest to iterate the original list and use `collectMany` to build up your new one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String::split(String)` to split the strings.

Use `Collection::flatten(Closure)` to convert each entry object into any number of output objects (so for this particular problem: convert each entry with unsplit `tag` value into a separate entry for each comma-separated value in `tag`). You can also use Java 8 streams and the `flatMap` method to achieve the same result, `flatten` is just specific to Groovy (not necessarily better).

I don't think it would be good to give you a full solution, though, so I'll leave that up to you.